# Kendo UI datasource sync() will not work

Tags: javascript, user-interface, kendo-ui, synchronization

In the code below, the fetch() and sync() methods are not doing  anything.
I am trying to see how the data in my localStorage gets updated and the methods are not updating it (example LS string is in the code)
Where am I going wrong?

```
function makeWorkingLS(collDesc, projDesc, Id, Description, ElapsedSeconds, ElapsedTime, WorkItemType){

//Create observable object from params
var activeTaskObject = kendo.observable ({
    client: collDesc,
    project: projDesc,
    taskId: Id,
    description: Description,
    elapsedSeconds: ElapsedSeconds,
    elapsedTime: ElapsedTime,
    comment: WorkItemType 
});
// example string in localStorage:
//{"client":"Morken Mindy","project":"Shazbat creation engine","taskId":183,"description":"Create the Shazbat 100% efficiency engine","elapsedSeconds":296803,"elapsedTime":"82h43m","comment":"Task"}  
// Convert to JSON string for localStorage
var activeTask = JSON.stringify(activeTaskObject);
console.info(activeTask);

//Write to localStorage
window.localStorage.setItem("activeTask",activeTask);

//Set it as the active datasource for updating to webservice
var activeTaskDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options){
            taskItem = JSON.parse(localStorage["activeTask"]);
        },
        update: {
            url: remUpd, //url var declared earlier in the process
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            client: "client",
            taskId: "taskId"
        },
        data: function(){
            return taskItem;
        }

    }
});

activeTaskDS.fetch(function(){
    activeTaskDS.data()[0].set("client", "NOBODY");
    activeTaskDS.sync();
    cosole.log("activeTaskDS.data()[0]  :  "+activeTaskDS.data()[0]); //should read 'NOBODY' but reads 'Morken Mindy'
});

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Neil.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is the problem actually, but I have to point some important things:

1. AFAIK, when you customize any `transport` methods you have to pass the data into a callback in the `options` object:

   ```
   transport: {
       read: function(options){
           taskItem = JSON.parse(localStorage["activeTask"]);

           // Tells the widget to handle that collection
           options.success(taskItem); 
       }
   }
   ```
2. In `schema.data` it seems that you want to pass your data through this method(correct me if I'm wrong). But this method isn't for that purpose. It is used just to tell the widget which field to read(in case of passing a string to it) or to read a property from a `response`, which comes as a parameter that you are not using. Check the second example [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.data). So this may not be right way to read the `taskItem` object as data;
3. Speaking about the `taskItem` object, it seems that its the base data of your dataSource but it isn't defined(at least on the snippet you posted). What I mean is, if you follow the step 1 you won't even need to *read* from that object no more.

Please let me know if this is helpful and if you need anyting more.

Comment: Thanks.  This has given me a better understanding of how I need to continue.

Comment: @NeilMcLeish but this answered your question or you have problems?

Comment: Thanks.  It has partially answered my question, but doesn't show me why the sync() function isn't actually updating the data in localStorage. 
For this particular project, I have found it far more effective to use an $.ajax() call.  There are a number of conditions which need to be checked when sending the data back to the web service and as Telerik's documentaiton for Kendo MobileUI only seems to show highly simplified examples, I have opted to go with what I know...

Comment: ...Thanks for your input, it is appreciated.  I'd like to keep this as unsanswered for now, until a more detailed explanation of the sync() operation is forthcoming, in terms of how it works and what it expects in the way of data.

Comment: Hi @DontVoteMeDown. Happy New Year!  No update to this.  I used a method whereby I pass the required data to a pure JS object, manipulate that as required, updating localStorage as needed until the data needs to be sent back to the web service; this last part done via ajax.  It is not ideal, I know, but time constraints forced that solution.

Comment: @NeilMcLeish ok, happy new year for you too.